# How to archive a subtask in Asana?

Tags: asana

How can I archieve a subtask in Asana? It is easy to archive the task but I couldn't find a way to archive a subtask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching here, I directed the question to @asana via Twitter and received the following reply: "no subtask archiving yet - but it’s on our list." See Twitter post at https://twitter.com/asana/status/280760677457608704